# Cannot install kernel-devsrc

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, yocto

I'm trying to set up my environment to use Yocto's generated SDK to compile my out-of-tree module, but for some reason, I'm getting an error.

> cp: cannot stat 'arch/arm/kernel/module.lds': No such file or directory

I'm using Poky distribution and meta-raspberrypi which is needed because I'm using the RPI ZeroW board.
Apart from this everything works fine. I'm able to compile the entire image and load it on the board.

Here is the line I've added to local.conf

> TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " kernel-devsrc"

as I've found in the documentation.

Also below you can find the whole log from the compilation.

```
DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
NOTE: Direct dependencies are ['virtual:native:/home/pp/yocto-hh/sources/poky/meta/recipes-bsp/u-boot/u-boot-tools_2020.07.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/pp/yocto-hh/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/binutils/binutils-cross_2.35.1.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/pp/yocto-hh/sources/poky/meta/recipes-kernel/kmod/kmod-native_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/pp/yocto-hh/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross_10.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/pp/yocto-hh/sources/poky/meta/recipes-support/gmp/gmp_6.2.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/pp/yocto-hh/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/pkgconfig/pkgconfig_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/pp/yocto-hh/sources/poky/meta/recipes-extended/xz/xz_5.2.5.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/pp/yocto-hh/sources/poky/meta/recipes-connectivity/openssl/openssl_1.1.1k.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/pp/yocto-hh/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/bison/bison_3.7.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/pp/yocto-hh/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/quilt-native_0.66.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/pp/yocto-hh/sources/poky/meta/recipes-extended/bc/bc_1.07.1.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/pp/yocto-hh/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc_2.32.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/pp/yocto-hh/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/patch/patch_2.7.6.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/pp/yocto-hh/sources/poky/meta/recipes-kernel/kern-tools/kern-tools-native_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/pp/yocto-hh/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/pseudo_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/pp/yocto-hh/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-runtime_10.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot']
NOTE: Installed into sysroot: []
NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: ['u-boot-tools-native', 'binutils-cross-arm', 'kmod-native', 'gcc-cross-arm', 'gmp-native', 'pkgconfig-native', 'xz-native', 'openssl-native', 'bison-native', 'quilt-native', 'bc-native', 'glibc', 'patch-native', 'kern-tools-native', 'pseudo-native', 'gcc-runtime', 'python3-native', 'gnu-config-native', 'autoconf-native', 'libtool-native', 'gtk-doc-native', 'automake-native', 'zlib-native', 'texinfo-dummy-native', 'readline-native', 'flex-native', 'attr-native', 'libmpc-native', 'mpfr-native', 'linux-libc-headers', 'gettext-minimal-native', 'libgcc', 'libnsl2-native', 'gdbm-native', 'libffi-native', 'bzip2-native', 'util-linux-native', 'sqlite3-native', 'libtirpc-native', 'm4-native', 'ncurses-native', 'libcap-ng-native', 'libpcre2-native']
DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install
cp: cannot stat 'arch/arm/kernel/module.lds': No such file or directory
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Execution of '/home/pp/yocto-hh/build/tmp/work/hhctrl-poky-linux-gnueabi/kernel-devsrc/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_install.109942' failed with exit code 1:
cp: cannot stat 'arch/arm/kernel/module.lds': No such file or directory
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command
```

The command I am using to produce the SDK is:

> bitbake name-of-my-image -c populate_sdk

What could be the problem here? Or how should I debug it? I've found a few touching on the subject and it seems that it should be already fixed, but for some reason, in my environment, it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing the module.lds file in the latest kernel. Apply the following source code as a patch in the kernel and build the image.

```
diff -Naur a/arch/arm/kernel/module.lds b/arch/arm/kernel/module.lds
--- a/arch/arm/kernel/module.lds    1970-01-01 05:30:00.000000000 +0530
+++ b/arch/arm/kernel/module.lds    2020-02-28 21:53:45.000000000 +0530
@@ -0,0 +1,5 @@
+/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 */
+SECTIONS {
+   .plt : { BYTE(0) }
+   .init.plt : { BYTE(0) }
+}
```